# Powershell windows shares without WMI

Tags: powershell-2.0, share

Simple question, though I fear I wont like the answer.  Currently I have a script for performing permission audits, get folders recursively then get-acl... so on and so forth.

I am using this line for a browsing part of the utility:

```
$Shares = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -ComputerName $text | Where-Object { $_.type  -ne 1}
```

This is working wonderfully however I want our lowest level techs to be able to run this.  They have permissions enough to perform all get-acl calls however they cannot navigate the broswer I wrote because they are not server admins, which they would have to be to perform a WMI call.

Long story short... is there a way to get a list of shares from a server without a WMI call?  I cannot find a way in my googlings.... but am having a hard time accepting that because all users can type "\servername\" into their explorer and BAM there they are... must be a powershell way to mimic that.

All hints, notions and wild out-there ideas are welcome

Comment: Does `net view \\computername` work for them? Type `net view /?` for help on this command. Run that from a command prompt or PS prompt.

Comment: write that as an actual response so i can give you a checkmark :)  ... going to need to do some string parsing but let that be the least of my worries... thanks for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `net view \\computername` work for them? Type `net view /?` for help on this command. Run that from a command prompt or PS prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work for you but try this:

```
([adsi]"WinNT://$computername/LanmanServer,FileService").Children | Select-Object @(
  @{n='CurrentUserCount';e={$_.CurrentUserCount}}
  @{n='Name';            e={$_.Name.Value}}
  @{n='Server';          e={$_.HostComputer | Split-Path -Leaf}}
  @{n='Path';            e={$_.Path.Value}}
  @{n='Description';     e={$_.Description.Value}}
)
```